# How to detect repeating random numbers?

Tags: algorithms, randomness, random-number-generator

What is the best way to detect repeating sequences of random numbers?

For example, say I got two random number generators (RNG). One of them has been tampered with and is repeating the sequence of random numbers after every N iterations.
The other RNG has not been tampered with and is producing random numbers like it should.

However, one of them is repeating its output every N bytes. N can be small or very large. How to detect this in a reliable and economic way?

Is using rolling hashes (like rsync does) a viable approach?

Comment: Doesn't [this older question](http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/7729/98) answer yours?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

does not yet seem to be a duplicate on this very site:
[cycle detection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_detection), see also [where hares catch up with turtles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3952805/proof-of-detecting-the-start-of-cycle-in-linked-list)
(would-be comment: the question first states repetition `every N iterations`, next `every N bytes`.)
(If it didn't carry over: for each PRNG to check, have a clone. For each change in state of the original one, trigger two in the clone. If the states get identical, you detected a cycle. No deterministic PRNG with limited state can avoid it. The states need not be as small as the results; they rarely are, nowadays, and the cycle lengths are *huge*.)